# Stopping chat spam from multiple accounts

Tags: spam, chat, vpn

Okay there is a chat system on my website that is always getting spammed by one person on multiple different accounts. I would prefer not to make chatting only to made accounts as to help new people chat and talk with the chatbox. Said spammer is using Tor to hide ips so every time we ban an account, they can come back whenever with a new ip. Is there any way to stop them or do I have to make the chat register only. Also they could just use a bunch of dump emails for that so thats not even fool proof.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind blocking access to anyone using the chat feature on your site through Tor then you can identify if the IP address being used is associated with a Tor exit node.

You can use `https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=101.180.130.40&port=` and simply change the IP address to your servers IP address and it will output a list of all Tor exit nodes that have access to your server. You can then simply run a regular download of the IP addresses and if the users IP address matches prevent that user from being able to post to your chat rooms.